# Show the order of the zero of the $f_n$ is equal to the order of a zero of $f$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $D \subset \Bbb{C}$ be a domain and let $f_n$ be a sequence of holomorphic functions converging uniformly to $f$ on compact subsets of $D$. If the $f_n$ have a zero of order $2$ in $D$ then either $f \equiv 0$ or $f$ has a zero of order $2$. Now is this just the Hurwitz theorem for the order 2 case? And is the proof similar to that of Hurwitz only with a specific order?

Comment: but it does on the closed unit disk, where the $f_n$ tend to $f$. @Apass.Jack

Comment: I suppose so, yes @Apass.Jack

Comment: @Apass.Jack doesn't Hurwitz state that $f$ and $f_n$ have the same order zero if the $f_n \rightarrow f$ uniformly on compact subsets of a domain?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the statement is false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a further issue in which your statement is not entirely correct. The sequence
$f_n(z)=z\cdot (z-1/n)$
converges to $f(z)=z^2$ uniformly on compact subsets of $D$ but of course $f_n$ has no zero of degree 2 while $f$ does.